# Delete files in a directory using Chef

Tags: chef-infra

I want to delete all files in a directory without deleting the directory itself.

Also, I don't want to use a execute block. If I use the following resource all the files along with the directory are deleted.

Code:

```
directory "/path/to/somedir/" do
      recursive true
      action :delete
end
```

Answer (score 0):

We don’t have a resource for this in Chef core. Sorry :( You can either use a ruby_block and some fancy FileUtils code or an execute.